# mySQL: queries for replacing individual parameters in datetime cells

Tags: mysql, wordpress, datetime

There are six parameters for DATETIME cells in mySQL tables, they are YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOURS, MINUTES and SECONDS.

How could I replace them individually in multiple cells using a single query?

Actually I've got the following working snippet that replaces the complete "time" part for multiple cells:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = CONCAT(DATE(post_date),' HH:MM:SS');
```

but I can't get on how to modify it to replace, for example, only the seconds.

Visually:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   original  value   |      new value      |
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2016-11-07 19:53:00 | // only seconds have changed
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2016-11-07 19:55:12 | // only minutes have changed
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2016-11-07 20:53:12 | // only hours have changed
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2016-11-22 19:53:12 | // only date has changed
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2016-07-07 19:53:12 | // only month has changed
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2009-11-07 19:53:12 | // only year has changed
---------------------------------------------
```

or

```
---------------------------------------------
|   original  value   |      new value      |
---------------------------------------------
| 2016-11-07 19:53:12 | 2017-11-07 19:42:12 | // year and minutes have changed
---------------------------------------------
```

I suppose it should be one query where I could decide what values (among year, month, date, hours, minutes or seconds) to keep intact and what to change.

Comment: "There are six parameters for DATETIME cells in mySQL tables".  I don't get this.  Why aren't you just using a `datetime`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Could you give us some example data and what you expect it to look like after it has been updated?

Comment: @JimNicholson, I have updated my question with more info